# Drupal 7 CVS, SVN or git access

Tags: svn, git, drupal, cvs, drupal-7

I'm interested in doing a site in Drupal 7 - rather than downloading the periodic source releases I'd like to grab the latest changes to Drupal using a version control system, be it CVS, SVN, git, etc. I'm not necessarily going to be contributing a module, though that might occur in the future. Any other developers out there working with the bleeding edge of Drupal? How do you stay up to date?

Comment: Have you considered using `drush`? I would avoid cvs and go with git if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [CVS instructions](http://drupal.org/node/320) and [Git instructions](http://drupal.org/node/803746#setup) on Drupal.org. You just need to use the appropriate revision to work with Drupal 7. As Drupal.org is [in the process of moving from CVS to Git](http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/git), I wouldn't recommend SVN.

Also, Drupal 7 is in beta, very close to stable release. "Bleeding edge" normally implies unstable, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 4):

Drush is quite good for downloading, installing and upgrading modules from drupal.org. A few more features have arrived since I last used it.

You can basically type `drush dl cck views token` etc and `drush enable views cck token` to download and install modules. I think it might also handle dependencies. If you want the latest (dev) modules you can just use cck-dev or similar for the module name. You get a bunch of commands for updating project code and modules and managing users and nodes. It's really a swiss army knife you can do a lot with.

- http://docs.drush.org/
- http://drupal.org/project/drush

Between git and cvs I would go for git. Git is just much more moddern and fast. It downloads things quickly, it won't scatter hidden directories all around your project and it's scheduled to be the next SCM for Drupal. CVS belongs in the 1990s.